# $GL(n,C)$ as a Lie group

Tags: group-theory

I understand that $SO(3)$, $SU(3)$ are Lie groups since they are associated with rotations (The S excludes reflection). Why is $GL(n,C)$ also a Lie group?

Comment: I think you wanted to ask this on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Because the matrices form a group (e.g., multiplication is closed and each matrix has an inverse) and they can be altered continuously (not merely discretely).